# org-notifications doesn't work

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, doom, notifications

There has been [many](https://github.com/sunnyhasija/Academic-Doom-Emacs-Config#notifications) [reports](https://github.com/doppelc/org-notifications/issues/4) [of](https://github.com/doppelc/org-notifications/issues/5) [org-notifications](https://github.com/doppelc/org-notifications) failing to work. Has anyone managed to set it up in the latest emacs?

Comment: Are you sure it's a problem with `org-notifications`? AFAICT, it uses `alert` under the covers and `alert`may need some configuration before it works  as expected. Does `(alert "FOO")` issue an alert that you can see? I only get it in `*Messages*`, it is cleared from the echo area too quickly. A different `alert-default-style` might work better but I have not tried.

Comment: 100% sure, (alert "test") works fine. `org-wild-notifier` is almost working as well. Thanks for mentioning `alert-default-style` - yes, it was one of the first gotchas, but it didn't help. The thing that perplexes me is just lack of documentation. It's extremely hard to debug notification packages (you can only try once every minute) so bad documentation can't be forgiven.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually went with org-wild-notifier (doom emacs):

```
(after! org
...
(org-wild-notifier-mode)
(setq alert-default-style 'libnotify
      org-wild-notifier-alert-time '(0)
      org-wild-notifier-keyword-whitelist nil
      ;; good for testing
      org-wild-notifier--alert-severity 'high
      alert-fade-time 50
      )
...
)
```

It works really well.

Gotchas:

- If you are using repeating tasks I recommend applying [this patch](https://github.com/akhramov/org-wild-notifier.el/issues/41#issuecomment-978811152) as well.
- Make sure not to use `org-schedule` command for "regular" tasks if you want repeating tasks to appear in the org-agenda "grid" (timeline).
- This may be really obvious, but make sure that the (active) timestamp is below the `:PROPERTIES:` "drawer".